# Curl: авторизация с сохранением сессии и куков в браузере

Tags: php, cookie, curl, сессия

Как с помощью curl передать куки из скрипта, где происходит авторизация на сайте в браузер? В результате этого можно было бы зайти на сайт как авторизованный пользователь на другой вкладке.

в require подключается [php-mod/curl](https://github.com/php-mod/curl) для работы с curl.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$curl = new Curl\Curl();
$curl->post('http://ex.com', array(
    'username' => 'qwe',
    'password' => 'qwe'
));
if ($curl->error) {
    echo $curl->error_code;
}
else {
    echo $curl->response;
}
```

Задача состоит в авторизации через скрипт на сайте таким образом, чтобы можно было зайти в этом же браузере на сайт и воспользоваться своей сессией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Как заставить работать.**

Сначала в кратце как работают сессии в ПХП.

По умолчанию в куки пишется значение PHPSESSID (меняется через session.name или session_name());
Когда поступает запрос к серверу и в куках установленно данное значение сервер по знчению тянет какие то сохраненные данные.

т.е.

Что бы решить проблему при открытие новой страницы надо что бы:

1. Server вернул cURL знчение session_id() и session_name() (куки) .
2. Что то передало эти значения Javascript (ajax).
3. Javascript открыл страницу http://server2/#cookie_name:cookie_id
4. Скрипт на странице с этих значений создал куку и скорее всего перегрузил её.

Скорее всего зароботает, но проблем не оберешся!

**Как правильно.**

Как правильный вариант надо смотреть в сторону oauth, openid ...

**Ну есть вариант 3**

Создать форму в HTML с инпутами username, password(можно невидимыми). Задать у формы `action="https://server2.com/auth/url` и засабмитить ее. По идее должно сработать без всяких бубнов с Curl.

Comment: т.е. мне от сервера надо получить куки сайта и записать их в браузер через js?

Comment: Тип того, но как я уже сказал, сильно не советую. И если нету доступа к коду второго сервера то и не получится.

Comment: Нету. А зачем мне доступ ко второму сайту? Мне просто нужно авторизоваться на нем через скрипт.

Comment: Тогда только oAuth, openId ... опять если второй сайт поддерживает!

Comment: Просто шаг 4 не выполнить без JS на стороне 2-го сервера. Это сделано для защиты.

Comment: Это не решает мою задачу

Comment: Добавил вариант 3 в ответ. Если они не наделали глупостей/дополнительных защит то должно сработать.